# My c++ Bubble sort function is not working

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I need to create a function called bubbleSort by passing the value instead of passing an array. But the bubbleSort function doesn't work at all. It still output the unsorted numbers which is the one that I assign to the only array in main(). The result should be shown as ascending order.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void bubbleSort(int, int);

int main(){   
    const int size = 10;
    int numbers[size] = { 100, 33, 49, 23, 84, 2, 72, 17, 82, 64 };

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++) {
            bubbleSort(numbers[i], numbers[j]);
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(int i, int j) {
    int temp;
    if (i > j) {
        temp = i;
        i = j;
        j = temp;
    }
}
```

the result is shown like this

```
100 33 49 23 84 2 72 17 82 64
100 33 49 23 84 2 72 17 82 64
```

Comment: In C++ arguments are by default passed *by value*. That means the value in the call (like `bubbleSort(numbers[i], numbers[j])`) are *copied* into the local arguments variables of the functions. Modifying these local variables will only modify these variables, not the original values used in the call.

Comment: The function you named `bubbleSort` is better called `swap`. The problem is however not in the name, but in the fact that it accepts its parameters by value, and cannot have any effect on anything outside. Please search what "pass by value" and "pass by reference" mean, and how to express the latter in C++.

Comment: Your issue is no different than this very simple program:  `void foo(int x) { x = 10; } int main() { int x = 0; foo(x);  std::cout << x; }`  You will be surprised that on output, `x` is still 0 after calling `foo`.  Basic C++ fundamentals, but for whatever reason, you were not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the parameter function of your Babel sort function to the function as a **call-by-reference** to be **applied** to the array you defined in the mine after completing the operation function.

like under :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void bubbleSort(int&, int&);

int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int numbers[size] = { 100, 33, 49, 23, 84, 2, 72, 17, 82, 64 };

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++)
        {
            bubbleSort(numbers[i], numbers[j]);
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(int &i, int &j) {
    int temp;
    if (i > j) {
        temp = i;
        i = j;
        j = temp;
    }
}

for example:
input :  100 33 49 23 84 2 72 17 82 64
out put :  2 17 23 33 49 64 72 82 84 100
```

For further reading, you can refer to the following site.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm